GORM `dbCreate: validate` takes 15+ minutes to throw SchemaManagementException. How to decrease this time?
In my grails app, I have dbCreate: validate. However, if I accidentally run grails run-app in InteliJ Idea when the database is out of sync with the domain objects, it takes 15+ minutes to fail and tell me what is wrong with the schema.  How can I get GORM to throw the SchemaManagementException sooner?
Start-up Log
Here's the log for when I was missing a table called theme. Note that it started the application at 15:45, but the first GORM error wasn't thrown until 15:59.
2024-05-08 15:45:46.315  INFO --- [  restartedMain] us.cloudcard.api.Application             : The following profiles are active: development

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security REST 3.0.1...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST

    ... with GORM support
2024-05-08 15:59:38.625 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'restLogoutFilterDeregistrationBean': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'restLogoutFilter' while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restLogoutFilter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStorageService' while setting bean property 'tokenStorageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenStorageService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTargetDatastore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [theme]
2024-05-08 15:59:38.875  WARN --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2024-05-08 15:59:39.006 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:485)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:472)
    at us.cloudcard.api.Application.main(Application.groovy:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restLogoutFilterDeregistrationBean': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'restLogoutFilter' while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restLogoutFilter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStorageService' while setting bean property 'tokenStorageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenStorageService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTargetDatastore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [theme]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1447)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restLogoutFilter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStorageService' while setting bean property 'tokenStorageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenStorageService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTargetDatastore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [theme]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1447)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenStorageService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTargetDatastore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [theme]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1447)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTargetDatastore' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [theme]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:720)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [theme]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1525)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1489)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760)
    ... 92 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [theme]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:310)
    ... 108 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [theme]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:287)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:86)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:212)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor96.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:207)
    ... 110 common frames omitted



DB Config
environments.development:
  dataSource:
    pooled: true
    driverClassName: software.aws.rds.jdbc.mysql.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    dbCreate: validate
    readOnly: false
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&enableClusterAwareFailover=false
    username: 'usr'
    password: 'pwd'
    properties:
      minIdle: 1
      maxActive: 8
      maxIdle: 1
      initialSize: 1
      maxWait: 5000
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 1800000
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1800000
      numTestsPerEvictionRun: 3
      testOnBorrow: true
      testWhileIdle: true
      testOnReturn: true
      validationQuery: SELECT 1
  dataSources:
    readReplica:
      readOnly: true
      driverClassName: software.aws.rds.jdbc.mysql.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&enableClusterAwareFailover=false
      username: 'usr'
      password: 'pwd'
    accessLogs:
      dbCreate: update
      driverClassName: software.aws.rds.jdbc.mysql.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb_two?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&enableClusterAwareFailover=false
      username: 'usr'
      password: 'pwd'

Additional Troubleshooting Notes
I determined that Hibernate is throwing the expected exception; but the exception being caught and suppressed by DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry, so I added some additional logging and found out that it's being thrown hundreds of times and each time takes 8-12 seconds, which is what is slowing everything down.
I still don't know why this is happening, but the following log demonstrates the problem.
Start-up Log with Custom Logging Added to DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry
2024-10-24 16:22:24.951  INFO --- [  restartedMain] us.cloudcard.api.Application             : The following profiles are active: development

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security REST 3.0.1...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST

    ... with GORM support
2024-10-24 16:23:19.978 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (BeanCurrentlyInCreationException) Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2024-10-24 16:23:19.983 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (BeanCurrentlyInCreationException) Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2024-10-24 16:23:19.995 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (BeanCurrentlyInCreationException) Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2024-10-24 16:23:20.002 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (BeanCurrentlyInCreationException) Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2024-10-24 16:23:20.009 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (BeanCurrentlyInCreationException) Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2024-10-24 16:23:20.016 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (BeanCurrentlyInCreationException) Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference
 ... 400+ Identical Log Entries Removed ...
2024-10-24 16:23:26.075 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (BeanCurrentlyInCreationException) Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2024-10-24 16:23:26.076 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (BeanCurrentlyInCreationException) Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2024-10-24 16:24:11.141 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (MappingException) An association from the table classification refers to an unmapped class: us.cloudcard.api.Classifier
2024-10-24 16:24:22.716 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (MappingException) An association from the table classification refers to an unmapped class: us.cloudcard.api.Classifier
2024-10-24 16:24:36.770 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (MappingException) An association from the table classification refers to an unmapped class: us.cloudcard.api.Classifier
2024-10-24 16:24:50.374 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (MappingException) An association from the table classification refers to an unmapped class: us.cloudcard.api.Classifier
2024-10-24 16:25:01.315 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Suppressed: (MappingException) An association from the table classification refers to an unmapped class: us.cloudcard.api.Classifier
... Processed Killed Manually ...

